# How should I load one Entity with Child collection Properties in my ViewModel?

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm

I have a custom data entry form which is bound to a ViewModel (VM).  The data entry form is suppose to display fields for the user to enter Employee data, i.e. 1 Employee per Form.  The EmployeeViewModel loads a bunch of data from web services like the one Employee (for updates) and many collections.  These collections consist of "Departments", e.g. an Employee belongs to one of many Departments, "Supervisors", e.g. an Employee is assigned to a Supervisor, and so on.  So, on my VM's constructor, I FetchData() from the service and I have to wait till it is completed.

So on OnLoadComplete, I assign the data returned to Employee, which is a property on my VM and also load all of the collections, like Departments, for the ComboBoxes.

Other properties on the VM are rendering NullExceptions on load b/c they look like this:

```
private Department_selectedDepartment;
public Department SelectedDepartment
{
   get
      { return this.Employee.Department; }          **// where error occurs**
   set
      {
          _selectedDepartment = value;
          this.Employee.Department = value;
          OnPropertyChanged("SelectedDepartment");
      }
}
```

In my XAML, I have the collections and their "Selected..."-parts as so:

```
<ComboBox
    ItemsSource="{Binding Departments, Mode=OneWay}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDepartment, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

When the getter of the SelectedDepartment hits as the VM loads, it says that the this.Employee" is null so I get an exception.

How are others doing this, i.e. wait till the Employee is loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
private Department _selectedDepartment;
public Department SelectedDepartment
{
   get
      { return _selectedDepartment;}   //return this.Employee.Department; 
   set
      {
          _selectedDepartment = value;
                                                               //this.Employee.Department = value;
          OnPropertyChanged("SelectedDepartment");
      }
}
```

and then load Employee from service, and also load all of the collections, like Departments....
Finally adding these lines for ComboBox binding:

```
Departments = new List<Department>(); //feed the collection by service calling result for ComboBox DataSource. 
SelectedDepartment = Employee.Department; //or, SelectedDepartment = Departments[0];
```

Hope it works.

Answer (score 3):

The way to do it is to make the SelectedDepartment simple, and then update it when the employee object has finished loading.

```
private Department _selectedDepartment;
public Department SelectedDepartment
{
   get
      { return _selectedDepartment; } 
   set
      {
          _selectedDepartment = value;
          OnPropertyChanged("SelectedDepartment");
      }
}
```

Then once your employee has finished loading, Select the correct department

```
SelectedDepartment = Departsments.Where(department=> department.ID == Employee.Department.ID ).First();
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to simply replace

```
 get
  { return this.Employee.Department; }          **// where error occurs**
```

with

```
 get { return Employee == null? null: Employee.Department; }
```

(or appropriate better code, like without ternary operators)

Doesn't make much sense to select anything in combobox when nothing is loaded yet, and error is not because you bind to null, but because you try to get Department from null reference.

One could argue about your decision to fetch stuff from inside viewmodel constructor? (if I understand correctly) but its out of scope of this question I guess.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to employ the "null object pattern" -- have a Department object that represents nothing.

So, you might replace

```
private Department _selectedDepartment;
public Department SelectedDepartment
{
    get { return this.Employee.Department; }
```

with

```
private Department _selectedDepartment = new Department { Name = string.Empty };
public Department SelectedDepartment
{
    get { return _selectedDepartment; }
```

You'll want some kind of method that applies all of the values to the properties when the Employee data is received.

Binding will work up front, and then when the data comes in the "null" Department can be replaced with the appropriate value.